# Error conexión a base de datos MySQL .

Tags: java, mysql, java-8, wamp

tengo el siguiente error cuando intento conectar a mi base de datos.

```
Excepcion conexion Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
```

**Mi clase de conexión es la siguiente:**

```
package cl.dao;



import java.sql.*;


public class DbConnection {
static String bd = "institute";
static String login = "root";
static String password = "";
static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/"+bd+"?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";


Connection conn = null;

public DbConnection(){
try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);

if(conn != null){
    System.out.println("Connection database ["+ conn +"] OK");
}
}catch(SQLException e)
{
    System.out.println("Excepcion conexion " + e.getMessage());

}catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
    System.out.println("Excepcion driver : "+ e.getMessage());
}
}

public Connection getConnection(){
    return conn;

}

public void disconnect(){
    System.out.println("Closing database: ["+conn+"] OK");
if(conn != null){
    try{
        conn.close();
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

}

**mi clase para probar la conexión es la siguiente :**

```
package cl.dao;

public class PruebaDB {



public static void main(String[] args) {
    DbConnection conn = new DbConnection();
    }

}
```

**Información adicional :**

MySQL : Versión 5.7.2.1 desde WampServer 3.1.3
Nombre base de datos : institute.

Quedo atento a sus respuestas.

Comment: Comprueba que tienes la el driver jdbc en el build path correctamente @TAEKCODER

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado que es MySQL, el puerto en el que normalmente está escuchando es el 3306 y tú no se lo has especificado en la cadena de conexión.

Prueba a modificarla así:

```
static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+bd+"?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
```

Si con esto siguieses teniendo, revisa la configuración de MySQL para ver qué puerto es el que has de usar

Comment: Al reemplazar la linea de código sigue ocurriendo el mismo error. Y efectivamente me encuentro utilizando el puerto : 3306 que viene por defecto.

Answer (score 0):

**Solución :**

1. Cambiar la versión del Driver jdbc 8.0 a la versión 5.1.
2. Reiniciar , Netbeans y Wampserver.
3. Modificar el método DbConnection().

**Código final :**

```
package cl.dao;


import java.sql.*;


public class DbConnection {
    static String bd = "institute";
    static String login = "root";
    static String password = "";
    static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+bd+"?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";


    Connection conn = null;

public DbConnection(){
try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);

    if(conn != null){
        System.out.println("Connection database ["+ conn +"] OK");
    }
}catch(SQLException e){
    System.out.println("Excepcion conexion " + e.getMessage());

}catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
    System.out.println("Excepcion driver : "+ e.getMessage());
}
}

public Connection getConnection(){
    return conn;

}

public void disconnect(){
    System.out.println("Closing database: ["+conn+"] OK");
if(conn != null){
    try{
        conn.close();
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}

}
```

Espero le sirva  alguien más.

Comment: puedes dar una justificación de cada cambio que realizaste??? por que los cambios realizado son la respuesta a tu problema.

Comment: Es decir, pusiste el puerto y cambiaste la clase del driver a una que sí existe?